# Rare characters trying to print a PDF made with iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, itext7

I'm writing this post because I have a problem when I try to print a PDF that I created with the library iText7. I opened the file with Google Chrome, my own pdf viewer, and with Adobe Acrobat and the text is as I added it via C# (with paragraphs). The problem comes when I try to print it. I used an .NET API and Google Chrome printer. The result is this:
[image: Print]

Link to PDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DPhNJrevSAz6UxaG-GLxwbOJKHqKd7XL/view?usp=sharing

The code to generate the PDF is this:

```
// Create the document
var ps = PageSize.A4;
var stream = new FileStream($@"{Internal.UserFileDataFolder}product_list_{DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}.pdf", FileMode.Create);
var writer = new PdfWriter(stream);
Document pdf = new Document(new PdfDocument(writer));
pdf.SetFontSize(11);

PdfFont font_robotoThin = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(MainResources.Roboto_Thin, PdfEncodings.CP1250, true);
PdfFont font_robotoRegular = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(MainResources.Roboto_Regular, PdfEncodings.CP1250, true);

// Create column definitions
float offSet = 10;
float columnWidth = (ps.GetWidth() - offSet * 2 + 10) / 3;
float columnHeight = ps.GetHeight() - offSet * 2;

// Define column areas
Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] 
{
    new Rectangle(offSet - 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth * 2 + 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)
};
pdf.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(pdf, columns));
```

Comment: Really need to examine the PDF to be able to comment, can you post it (or a similarly not working example) somewhere please ?

Comment: @KenS Ready, the link is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DPhNJrevSAz6UxaG-GLxwbOJKHqKd7XL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry but I'm afraid I can't see a problem. The fonts are embedded, and use a standard Encoding, so even if the PDF reader can't find the embedded fonts a substitute should still provide sensible output. You haven't said exactly how you are printing the file, but it looks to me like the API you are using is treating the file as text or something, not a PDF file. Do you get **any** sensible text at all, Eg "%PDF-1.7" on the output ?